# Batch files - Replacing the 5th line in a text file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have spent some time online looking for an answer to this but I have been unable to get anything to work.

I have a text file with around 1700 lines. It doesn't matter what is on any of these lines but I always want to replace line 5 with the same string.

For Example the text file is called test.txt. The lines go something like:

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. FMOD       'random stuff here'
6. f

I always want to replace the 5th line (which always starts with FMOD but had random stuff after that) with a set string. This has to be done quite a few times and is done manually at the moment, It would really help me if it could be done through a batch file which is used anyway and other people might want to use this so I was hoping to do it all natively in the batch file without the use of additional files.

Much appreciated in advance,

Matt

Comment: Can any other line start with `FMOD` or will only line 5 start with FMOD

Answer (score 1):

Using pure native batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "file=yourFile.txt"
set "newLine5=NewLine5Here"

>"%file%.new" (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') do for /f "delims=:" %%N in ("%%A") do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enabableDelayedExpansion
    if "!ln:~0,6!" equ "5:FMOD" (echo(!newLine5!) else echo(!ln:*:=!
    endlocal
  )
)
move /y "%file%.new" "%file%" >nul
```

The above is limited to ~8191 bytes per line. The speed will probably not be bad for 1700 lines, but it is relatively slow.

Life is really simple if you use my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that can do a regular expression find/replace on file contents, including the option to incorporate user supplied JScript code to tailor the result. It is pure script that will run natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

This JREPL solution is ***much*** faster and more robust than any pure batch solution:

```
jrepl "^FMOD.*" "NewLine5Here" /jbegln "skip=(ln!=5)" /f "yourFile.txt" /o -
```

Comment: Dave, I think I get an idea of how it functions, but is `ln` a variable that is initialised by the `/jbegln` switch?  Those of us with little Jscript experience aren't sure.

Comment: @foxidrive - It is described in the help near the end. It is one of the predefined global variables available to user supplied JScript code. It holds the line number of the currently processing line. skip is another predefined variable that controls whether the line is matched or skipped.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  `Repl` had a small learning curve for me but `Jrepl` seems to require a lot more extra knowledge of Jscript and I'm not in a position to study that at this time - hence I'm trying to pick up very simple tips when I see them.

Comment: JREPL is only more difficult if you use the new JScript features (or the /T option). But this problem does indeed require the JScript features