# (Batch) Taking number from text file and minusing it

Tags: batch-file, math, text-files

Hi im trying to make a simple batch game in my free time and i ran into a problem. I want an amount in a text file to be minused by X amount.

This is the part that finds the number in the text file.

```
:money
cls
set "xprvar="
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%p in 
(%userprofile%\variables.txt) do (echo You Have %%p Coin/s& goto break)
goto coin

:break
pause
```

This is the part where it takes away X amount from the amount written in the text file but it dosent want to work and i dont know how to fix it.

```
:moneytaker
set /a new=%money%-%%p
echo = %new%
pause
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch files - Replacing the 5th line in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152561/batch-files-replacing-the-5th-line-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doesn't work, because `%%p` is no longer defined, when the `for` loop is finished. Use a variable instead:

```
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%p in (%userprofile%\variables.txt) do set coins=%%p
echo You have %coins% Coin/s
...
echo before: %money%
set /a money-=coins
echo after: %money%
```